# How to programatically disable internet connectivity

Tags: customization, web-access

Internet connectivity may cause slows evaluations or cause unexpected problems (particularly in GUIs) when working in an environment with slow Internet or no Internet access at all.  I know how to stop the Internet connectivity using the Preferences menu ([Allow the Wolfram System to access the Internet](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/InternetConnectivity.html#713097862)) but I want to know if there a way to stop Internet connectivity programmatically.

Comment: `$AllowInternet = False` ?

Comment: This certainly works as well as the CurrentValue approach.  It would be nice to know if there is any difference between the two approaches.

Comment: Good question, I do not know (you could ask Carl). But I noticed that once setting `CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, "AllowDownloads"]`, it will also set `$AllowInternet`. The reverse it not true.

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, "AllowDownloads"]=False;
```

to disable the "Allow the Wolfram System to access the internet" preference.

Comment: It might be better to do this on the `$FrontEndSession` (if possible)

Comment: Do you know how your approach differs from $AllowInternet=False?

Comment: One bit of information I found is that to use SendMail both parameters need to be set to True.